# FileSystemWatcher - 3 events during File copy

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, .net

Is that, every time FileSystemWatcher will generate **3 events** when a file is copied to the FileWatcher folder

Example : Am getting **Created - > Changed -> Changed**(during new file)  Or **Changed - > Changed - > Changed** (during overwrite of existing file) event , when file is copied to the FileWatcher folder using File.Copy(source,watcherFolder,true).

Am getting 3 events when copying file of different size (1kb , 67kb, 100MB, 500MB, 1 GB files). i have registerd for Created and Changed event in FileSystemWatcher

Comment: Yes, FileSystemWatcher will tell you about specific writes to a file as Changed events.  If that's not what you want, please provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about the multiple events you are receiving, this is a normal behavior. File copy can raise multiple event.

You can check the changes in [**FileSystemEventArgs.ChangeType**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemeventargs.changetype.aspx) and ignore some of the events. Here is the [WatcherChangeTypes Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6xf43e0.aspx).

Take a look at [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Remarks.

About the [**Created**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created.aspx) event, it will be raised in the destination folder.

> For example, you create two instances of FileSystemWatcher. FileSystemWatcher1 is set to watch "C:\My Documents", and FileSystemWatcher2 is set to watch "C:\Your Documents". If you copy a file from "My Documents" into "Your Documents", a Created event will be raised by FileSystemWatcher2, but no event is raised for FileSystemWatcher1. Unlike copying, moving a file or directory would raise two events. From the previous example, if you moved a file from "My Documents" to "Your Documents", a Created event would be raised by FileSystemWatcher2 and a Deleted event would be raised by FileSystemWatcher1.

Comment: when a file is being copied to the file watcher folder, how can i identify whether the file is completely copied into the file watcher folder ?

Comment: Edited my answer : you have to watch the Created event on your destination folder (ie. the directory to which the file was copied).

Comment: @Snober Test if the file is locked - if you do not know how I can post code. but not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should look for a file being created and then attempt a file lock to determine if it is fully copied.

```
    while ($true)
    {
        try{ 
            [IO.file]::openwrite("<insert file path>").close()
            break
        }
        catch { start-sleep -Seconds 60 }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in control of the file copy operation, a simple thing to do is to create the file with a temporary name and rename it once it has been copied. Let the `FileSystemWatcher` watch for the `Rename` event. This event is fired only once.